# How to serialize a object that has complex property in wcf only one time?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I want to serialize a  object called `ComplexModel` that has complex property in wcf,at first I use `List<SimpleModel> SimpleModel` as  a property of my object.

**My wcf Model**

```
  [DataContract]
//[KnownType(typeof(SimpleModel[]))]
public class ComplexModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }

    //change List<SimpleModel> to SimpleModelCollection
    [DataMember]
    public SimpleModelCollection SimpleModel { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
///  defined a custom type to implement the IEnumerable interface instead of List SimpleModel
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
[CollectionDataContract]
[KnownType(typeof (SimpleModel))]
public class SimpleModelCollection : IEnumerable<SimpleModel>
{
    public IList<SimpleModel> List = new List<SimpleModel>();

    public SimpleModelCollection()
    {
    }

    public SimpleModelCollection(IList<SimpleModel> objs)
    {
        List = objs;
    }

    public void Add(SimpleModel obj)
    {
        List.Add(obj);
    }

    //IEnumerable<SimpleModel> member
    public IEnumerator<SimpleModel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return List.GetEnumerator();
    }

    //IEnumerable member
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return List.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class SimpleModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MumName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Point { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

I debug and it tell me I have not implement the IEnumerable interface.So I try to implement it,but it still tell me to implement the IEnumerable interface. If I have the other complex property, I have to define the other collection.Is there a better way to avoid  this situation?Why Why  is better  to return xml or json format instead of object(entities) directly?

**My wcf interface**

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface ITestService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    ComplexModel DoWork();
}
```

**My wcf class**

```
public class TestService1 : ITestService1
{
    public ComplexModel DoWork()
    {
        var SimpleModels = new SimpleModelCollection();
        SimpleModels.Add(new SimpleModel
        {
            MumName = "def",
            BirthDate = DateTime.MinValue,
            Point = 99
        });
        SimpleModels.Add(new SimpleModel
        {
            MumName = "hig",
            BirthDate = DateTime.Now,
            Point = 100
        });
        return new ComplexModel
        {
            Age = 10,
            Name = "abc",
            SimpleModel = SimpleModels
        };
    }
}
```